How can I mark the parts of the car in react native
I want it to show the parts when I click on the numbers.
2-left door.
9-right door.

I can also show it as painted, changed, locally painted or original. My main purpose is to show the damage information to the car. I don't know how to do this. Does it make sense to do it on a single picture or to take 13 pieces of pictures and combine them?

Either approach could work.  As asked, this question is not on-topic for Stack Overflow, as it's both very broad and subject to varying opinion-based answers.  You should revise your post to ask a specific, answerable question EG, about code you wrote that didn't work, or how to capture the coordinates of a touch/press in React-Native.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
